# how to add permission to an ftp account

Tags: permissions, ftp

I add a new subdomain with plesk , and with command line I've copied a directory from the root to the directory of the subdomain , when I connect with an ftp account I don't have the right permission for this folder , and I can't change them from the ftp

Comment: Did you copy the directory as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the following file with this command : `nano /etc/passwd`
Then search for the user name : ctl+w username in my case anass

then copy the two numbers in right of the user name `anass:x:1000:1000` , in this case `1000:1000`

Connect with root and type this command : `chown -R 1000:1000 yourdirectory`
chow mean change owner